# Как отловить состояние активности отладчика?

Tags: отладка, javascript

Необходимо защитить выполнение JS от просмотра выполняемых сценариев.
Вопрос: как отловить активность (вкл-выкл) того или иного отладчика. Например, Firebug?

Answer (score 3):

Firebug можно отловить, например по наличию на странице элемента firebug'а. Там div рисуется :)
На gmail так сделано, если зайти в почту со включенным firebug'ом, то наверху будет надпись "Gmail работает быстрее с отключенным firebug'ом" :)

Comment: Гениально! И как это я раньше не додумался :)
Спасибо !

Comment: Хотя любопытно.. Что-то не могу отловить этот элемент :)
Может кто подскажет какой элемент нужно искать ?:)

Comment: Элементы firebug'а: .firebugCanvas, .firebugHighlight, .firebugLayoutBoxParent, .firebugRuler, .firebugRulerH, .firebugLayoutBox ну и т.д. Все перечислять не буду. Найти эти элементы firebug'ом практически невозможно, он их вырезает как может. Но иногда при использовании iframe firebug толи не успевает, толи глючит, но элементы не удаляет из себя и самим firebug'ом можно отыскать их :)

Comment: Чтобы найти классы, о которых говорил я, нужно: 1. Открыть firebug. 2. Выделить все. 3. rClick->View Selection Source. Найти классы css firebug'а можно хоть на этой странице :)